# Loopback mock session

Tags: javascript, express, session-variables, loopback

I'm using loopback with express session to store cartId.

But I need to inject cartId on request session in order to make my tests work.

So on my remote method I have

```
Cart.get = function (req, cb) {
    Service.getCart(req, req.session.cartId)
    .then(function (result) {
        cb(null, result);
    })
    .catch(cb);
};

Cart.remoteMethod(
    'get',
    {
        accepts: { arg: 'req', type: 'object', 'http': { source: 'req' } },
        returns: { arg: 'cart', type: 'object', root: true },
        http: { path: '/', verb: 'get' }
    }
);
```

How can I force req.session.cartId for my tests?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your case correctly, you can do something similar to the code below, you would just add another param (cardId) to your get method definition:

```
 Cart.remoteMethod('get',{
      accepts: [
        { arg: "caseId", type: "number", http: {source:'path'} },
        { arg: 'req', type: 'object', http: { source: 'req' } }
      ],
      returns: { arg: 'cart', type: 'object', root: true },
      http: { path: '/:caseId/getCart', verb: 'get' }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use "get" remote method and pass cartId through URL or if you have concern about cartId visibility on URL then you can use post method as following code.
Use following cart.js file and explore in loopback api.

```
module.exports = function (Cart) {

  Cart.getCart = function (cartId, cb) { 
    Cart.findOne({
        where: { cartId  :  cartId } 
    }, function (err, cart) { 
      cb(null, users);
    });
  };

 Cart.remoteMethod('getCart', {
    accepts: {
      arg: "id",
      type: "string",
      required: true
    },
    returns: {
      arg: 'cart',
      type: 'object'
    },
    http: {
      path: '/:cartId/getcart',
      verb: 'get'
    }
  });

};

get call : http://HOST:IP/cart/YourID/getcart
```

You will retrieve cart by Id.
Hope this will work.